# Not able to add new rule in web.config dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, web-config

I have applied url rewrite in my application and add some rules in web.config as

```
<modulesSection>
    <rewriteModule>
      <rewriteOn>true</rewriteOn>
      <rewriteRules>
         <rule source="About/About-Demo" destination="About/Demo.aspx"/>
      </rewriteRules>
      </rewriteModule>
</modulesSection>
```

Now I want to add new rule from code behined. I have used following code...

```
public void NEWTEST(string source, string destination)
{       
    XDocument xml = XDocument.Load( Path.Combine( Server.MapPath("~").ToString(), "web.config"));


    if (!RuleExists(source, destination))
    {  
        XElement elem = new XElement("rule");
        elem.SetAttributeValue("source", source);
        elem.SetAttributeValue("destination", destination);
        xml.Element("rewriteRules").Add(elem); // Error occured
        xml.Save(Path.Combine( Server.MapPath("~").ToString(), "web.config"));
    }
}


public  bool RuleExists(string source, string destination)
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~").ToString(), "web.config"));

        return doc.Descendants("rewriteRules").Elements()
                  .Where(e => e.Attribute("source").Value == source
                  && e.Attribute("destination").Value == destination).Any();
    }
```

But at line " xml.Element("rewriteRules").Add(elem); // Error occured" I have getting an error 
"System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.".
Please give me the solution. Is this is aright way to creating a new rule if not then give me the right way to do this.thanxx in advance

Comment: I got this to work using `xml.Descendants("rewriteRules").First().Add(elem);`, but I'm not sure that's the best way and I'm not sure why your code isn't working.  I even tried adding in `Root` before `Element`.

Comment: @Tim Thanks a lot Sir  your code xml.Descendants("rewriteRules").First().Add(elem); worked as I want. One more thing some where i read that dynamically updating web.config is harmful is this is true...

Comment: Changing the web.config, as I understand it, will cause the application to restart, so you'd want to be careful doing that, but I'm not 100% sure on that.

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure if using xml to modify a configuration file will work out. here is what worked out for us [Click Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228054%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)!

There are predefined classes to do this. check them

Answer (score 0):

Following code worked for me..

```
 public bool RuleExists(string source, string destination)
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~").ToString(), "web.config"));

    return doc.Descendants("rewriteRules").Elements()
              .Where(e => e.Attribute("source").Value == source
              && e.Attribute("destination").Value == destination).Any();
}
public void DefineUrlRewrite(string source, string destination)
{
    XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~").ToString(), "web.config"));


    if (RuleExists(source, destination))
    {
        //element is already in the config file
        //do something...
        lblMsg.Text = "This Rule is already exists, choose another one!!! <br/>";
    }
    else
    {
        XElement elem = new XElement("rule");
        elem.SetAttributeValue("source", source);
        elem.SetAttributeValue("destination", destination);

        xml.Descendants("rewriteRules").First().Add(elem);
        xml.Save(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~").ToString(), "web.config"));
    }
}
```